# Are these numbers sufficient for calculating $P(\alpha|\beta,\gamma)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given three probabilities $Pr(\beta|\alpha)$, $Pr(\gamma|\alpha)$ and $Pr(\alpha)$; and that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are conditionally independent given $\alpha$, can $Pr(\alpha|\beta, \gamma)$ be calculated?

My solution:

$$\begin{align}
Pr(\alpha|\beta, \gamma) &= \frac{Pr(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)}{Pr(\beta, \gamma)} \\
&= \frac{Pr(\alpha) Pr(\beta, \gamma|\alpha)}{Pr(\beta, \gamma)}
\end{align}$$

Since $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are independent given $\alpha$, we can get:

$Pr(\alpha|\beta, \gamma) = \frac{Pr(\alpha) Pr(\beta|\alpha) Pr(\gamma|\alpha)}{Pr(\beta, \gamma)}$

Three probabilities in the numerator are given but the denominator is not, then the given constraints are not sufficient to calculate $Pr(\alpha|\beta, \gamma)$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Bayes Theorem and then use the independence given $\alpha$:
$$\mathbb{P}(\beta, \gamma) = \sum_{\alpha} \mathbb{P}(\beta, \gamma | \alpha)\mathbb{P}(\alpha)= \sum_{\alpha}\mathbb{P}(\beta | \alpha) \mathbb{P} (\gamma | \alpha) \mathbb{P} (\alpha) $$

P.S.: I'm assuming you are given those probabilities for each $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ spans in a discrete set.

Comment: I think the Bayesian tables are given, then $P(\beta,\gamma)$ becomes calculable.

Comment: Yes, you need either tables or an analytical expression in function of $\alpha$.

Comment: No worries. I was about to ask what you meant :)

Comment: Is it right that we can know the probability for each $\alpha$ if $Pr(\alpha)$ is given as described in the question?

Comment: Actually, I assumed you were given $\mathbb{P}(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha$. Otherwise you cannot apply Bayes Theorem.